# Prevent insert if user trying to insert from multiple computers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which I do some checks before any insert for any user. I use a stored procedure for data insert. There is a problem
if the user uses two computers and tries to insert almost at the same time (click on the insert button in both computers simultaneously ). They can pass the checks and insert invalid data. How can I prevent them?

I have tried to do the checks in the stored procedure right before the insert statement and still not working.
I also used a transaction block.

this is the procedure:

```
BEGIN TRAN
    IF 
        (
            (
            SELECT SUM(Weight) FROM table
            WHERE 
                MojavezCode = @certId   AND 
                goodsTypeId = @goodType AND 
                isDeleted   = 0         AND 
                DateSabt BETWEEN @StartDore AND @EndDore
            ) 
            > @sahmiye
        )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('---',15,18)
        RETURN   -9523
    END

    INSERT INTO table
    (
       FromKharidarID,
       AmelKharidID,
       DateSabt,
       TimeSabt,
       MojavezCode,
       
       isDeleted,
       goodsTypeId,
       InsertUserIp,
       UniqID,
       Weight

       
    )
    VALUES
    (  @kharidarId,    
       @EtehadyeId,    
        ( SELECT dbo.SolarDate(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111))),  
        ( SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 108)),  
        LTRIM(RTRIM(@certId)) ,  
           
       0, 
       @goodType  ,   
       LTRIM(RTRIM(@userIP)), 
       @uniqueId,
       @Wight
        )
    COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: `USE XACT_ABORT ON; BEGIN TRANSACTION txn; /* do stuff */ COMMIT TRANSACTION txn;`

Comment: The insert still happens, because there is no problem inside the transaction, the problem is two simultaneous attempts from two different computers and i cant stop them.

Comment: What you describe is a bug in the code that won't be fixed by limiting a server meant to handle hundreds of clients concurrently. At the very least post the stored procedure code and how you call it

Comment: The stored procedure is very simple and has just an insert.

Comment: And yet it fails. If it performs checks, it's not just an insert. Post the code instead of making people guess. Something's weird with those checks that work for one call but not another. They statements may be wrong or the checks may be wrong. Or they should be performed in triggers. Or perhaps you're using the wrong isolation level

Comment: checks are in other procedures.

Comment: Post these too. Without any code or details, the question will be closed. Applications simply don't restrict concurrent calls. The code is doing something unusual, we can't guess what that is

Comment: The check procedure is 1000 lines, i cant post it

Comment: No, this is about transactions, and that is the piece of code that should be shown.

Comment: I do not have the time to put together a good answer here, maybe someone else will, just a couple of hints: I would `ROLLBACK` the transaction before returning in case of error, I am not sure from the top of my head but I think you are leaving an open transaction dangling around there; secondly, to the issue of handling concurrency, try and put a `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` on top of the script and see if that doesn't make any difference (you get *read* locks as well with that).  Then read the docs...

Comment: where should i put the rollback? no error occurs .

Comment: Just before the `RAISERROR` I would say, but I'd have to double-check the details, a couple of years have passed since I have had to solve similar problems: just let me stress again that my hints here are indeed *not* meant to be an answer.  For example, it is important and not trivial at all handling errors in conjunction with transactions, there are specific patterns that work with vs without try-catch.

Comment: You may be able to use [lock hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver16) in your checks so that other processes are blocked until the SP releases the lock(s). That may impact performance more than you can tolerate. You could use an [application lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to block access to whatever you define to be a _resource_.

Comment: @SamanKhan1 - please read about creating a [mcve]. You don't need to post 1000 lines, but you *do* need to provide all relevant parts within your question. Further, comments are not the place to expand upon this - you should be editing your question to provide specific details.

Answer (score 1):

You need `WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK)` hints on the `IF` subquery, otherwise it will not lock those rows. You also should use `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and `THROW` to ensure a correct rollback.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;
IF (
       (
            SELECT SUM(Weight)
            FROM table WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK)
            WHERE 
                MojavezCode = @certId   AND 
                goodsTypeId = @goodType AND 
                isDeleted   = 0         AND 
                DateSabt BETWEEN @StartDore AND @EndDore
       )
       > @sahmiye
   )
BEGIN
    THROW 50001, N'---', 1;
END;

INSERT INTO table
    (
       FromKharidarID,
       AmelKharidID,
       DateSabt,
       TimeSabt,
       MojavezCode,
       isDeleted,
       goodsTypeId,
       InsertUserIp,
       UniqID,
       Weight
    )
    VALUES
    (  @kharidarId,    
       @EtehadyeId,    
        ( SELECT dbo.SolarDate(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111))),  
        ( SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 108)),  
        LTRIM(RTRIM(@certId)) ,  
       0, 
       @goodType  ,   
       LTRIM(RTRIM(@userIP)), 
       @uniqueId,
       @Wight
    );

COMMIT TRAN;
```

As a side note: you shouldn't store date and time in separate fields, instead just use `datetime2`. And you certainly shouldn't store them in `nvarchar` fields.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `THROW 50001, N'---', 1;` part? Wouldn't it be better overall to invert the `IF` logic to guard the `INSERT`? Or do `INSERT INTO t ( ... ) SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM t )` ?

Comment: `THROW` will end the batch immediately, so it guards it. Yes you could do that, but then you don't have a custom error message.